# Backbone underscore sum value

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in backbone and I want to know if is possible to sum inside a template value of the object.
For example I have this piece of template  in underscore:

```
<% _.each(room1.combinations, function(room2) { %>
     <div>
        <div class="tot"><p>TOTAL:<span id="totale_<%= room2[0].attributes.id %>"></span></p>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <% _.each(room2, function(room) { %>
                 <span><%= room.attributes.price %> EUR</span>

            <% }); %>
            <input type="button" class="submit-ricerca prenota-bt" name="buy" value="BUY">
         </form>
     </div>
<% }); %>
```

I want to put into the span with class total the sum of the price of each element inside it.
Is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just sum the prices (using [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)) and put them there:

```
<p>TOTAL:<span id="totale_<%= room2[0].attributes.id %>"><%=
   _.reduce(room2, function(sum, room){return sum+room.attributes.price;}, 0)
%></span>
```

Comment: Oh my god! is perfect! The only thing is to to put parseFloat before room.attributes.price for security but works fine +1 ASAP I accept it!

Comment: Is possible for you to sum only the visible value? because you have answer at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487411/underscore-check-previous-record-in-each/17487822?noredirect=1#comment25418493_17487822 and if I apply this the sum it would be different if I don't print result right?

Comment: No. You could by simply repeating the condition, but that's bad practise. Instead, filter the `room2` array before you're showing it and then iterate it straight.