# Underscore check previous record in each

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in backbone and a template with underscore.
I want to know if is possible to check a value inside a each of the previous record or something to check.
Suppose that I have record like this:
{
   id: 1,
   level:1,
   jump_level:2
},
{
   id: 2,
   level:2,
   jump_level:0
}

Into my each I want to check if previous record has the same jump_level of the actual level because I want to tell that if i have to not print next record.

This is a piece of my template:

```
<div>
<% _.each(room2, function(room) { %>
     //I would like to write an if like this:
     // if exist previous room -> check if jump_level == level if yes don't print span
     <span> <%= room.attributes.id %></span>                                           
<% }); %>
</div>
```

Is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can quite literally translate that to JS code:

```
<% _.each(room2, function(room, i) {
       if ( !(i>0 && room2[i-1].jump_level == room.jump_level) ) { %>
           <span> <%= room.attributes.id %></span>
<%     }
   }); %>
```

Comment: How can `room2` be undefined when that's the array you're iterating over?

Answer (score 0):

just store the state of the previous `room` in a "global" variable, you could use that each consulting that state setted with a default base value the first time.